# Convergence of $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1} - a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be any convergent sequence of real numbers and let
$x_n = a_{n+1} − a_n$ for each $n \in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that the sum $x_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity is a convergent series and find its sum.

Comment: @Norbert: I am not sure whether it is good to use `\limits` in the title - for the reasons similar to: [Why no use displaystyle in titles?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/why-no-use-displaystyle-in-titles/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, \limits often used in question om MSE, and for my taste I don't like \sum signs without specification range of summing index. If you don't agree you can rollback or edit it in an appropriate way

Comment: @Norbert You're right, using \limits in the titles seems to be ok. (I remembered this was discussed somewhere and found [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2709198#2709198).)

Answer (score 10):

This is called a telescopic sum. Try to write explicit expression for the $\sum\limits_{k=1}^N x_k$. You will see that most terms will cancel out. Then take a limit when $N\to \infty$.

Hint

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^N x_k = (a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_4-a_3)+\ldots+(a_{N-2}-a_{N-3})+(a_{N-1}-a_{N-2})=
$$
$$
a_2-a_1+a_3-a_2+a_4-a_3+\ldots+a_{N-2}-a_{N-3}+a_{N-1}-a_{N-2}=a_{N}-a_1
$$

We have just computed the partial sum. In order to pass to the infinite series take limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$.
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k=
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^N x_k\right)=
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\left(a_N-a_1\right)=
\left(\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}a_N\right)-a_1
$$

Comment: could you elaborate more please?